# Appium Upgrade to 1.5.3 : How to resolve "Permission denied" error?

Tags: automated-testing, appium, mobile-automation

Small issue:
I am opening one file on mac programatically. But I am getting error of Permission denied

How can I resolve this error & grant permission?

Comment: show us a screenshot? which version of OS you are using?

Comment: Appium latest released version. Do you need screenshot really for this?

Comment: We certainly need more info that you've given Narendra.  Please imagine reading this question as someone else.  There could literally be thousands of reasons for your situation.  Do you have the information needed to allow us to give an accurate and meaningful answer ?

Comment: yes, Agree. but really unable to identify what all should I share to give you an accurate scenario and my stuck point details :(
I am programmatically trying to open a file which containing my shell script [on mac] When I am trying to execute that file, I observed Permission denied error. Tried using chmod 777 or a+w but does not work :(